# iOS In App Purchase with Rails Backend

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, in-app-purchase

I'm having some confusions when creating in app purchase strategy for my iOS app. Some background info below;

I have an iOS app and a web app which both will work in subscription model. The backend has been developed in Ruby on Rails.

Currently I'm trying to develop the iOS auto-renewal in app purchase. I came across couple of gems which helps to verify in app purchase receipts (e.g [Venice](https://github.com/nomad/venice)). I get that the whole point of verifying the receipts from the backend rather then the client is to make it secure and to be able to keep a copy of the receipt in your own server.

I can foresee a huge problem as explained below;

A user can create an account using the iOS app and subscribe to the service by paying X dollars monthly using x@x.com apple id. By doing this I will have the record of this user in my backend including the expiry date of his subscription which will enable for me to track if he renewed his subscription or not. The problem arises when this user logs out from the app and creates another user. Since his apple id is still x@x.com and as account email address or id doesn't matter at all when making a purchase from apple, the expiry date will still be a month ahead since he just subscribed with his previous account the new user will be identified as an already paid customer. Boom! now his friend can login with this account using the web app and enjoy it without paying a quid.

If this makes sense for you, there must be a solution for this hack. I know that Netflix uses Apple's IAP, Spotify used for a very long time.

Also gems like Venice, they don't put a thorough documentation on their github page therefore I don't know if this problem is solved by them out of the box. Just wanted to check with you guys and I'm sure many of you thought about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're attributing the auto-renewing purchase to a user in your database you will also want to attribute the `original_transaction_id` that is found in the receipt. Store this ID with the `expires_date` and ignore or error any receipts containing the same `original_transaction_id` the API receives that are already attributed to a different user in the database.

The `original_transaction_id` will never change for the iTunes user, even if they unsubscribe and re-subscribe at a later date it will remain the same. It will also remain the same if they upgrade/downgrade the duration of the subscription when the product IDs are of the same subscription family.

If you're looking for an alternative to Venice take a look at the [itunes_receipt_validator](https://github.com/mbaasy/itunes_receipt_validator) gem (**full disclosure:** I am the author). It validates the signatures and decodes of both the *deprecated* transaction receipts and the *newer* grand unified receipts locally without connecting to Apple's API, but also provides the functionality to retrieve the updated receipt and receipt info from the Apple API.

Comment: Hi Marc thanks for your answer. I ended up using the same strategy and works pretty great. As this is the solution to my problem I will accept it as an answer. Also, I found it very useful to run a daily cronjob and check each receipt in my database to see if they are expired or not. By doing this, I don't actually wait for users to open the app to get the most recent receipt in my database.